# How to get 2d array to split into rows dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am making a tictactoe game with javascript for school and I am at a standstill. With the way I have it set up my game doesn't display as a game of tictactoe would look. Is there a way for me to split the 2d array to have 3 rows and 3 columns?

```js
function TicTacToe() {
 this.board = [[0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0]
 ];
 this.showhtml = toHTML;
}

function toHTML() {
 var gametable = document.getElementById("tictable");
 for (var i = 0; i < this.board.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < this.board[i].length; j++) {
   gametable.innerHTML += ("<td>" + this.board[i][j] + "</td>");
  }
 }
}

tic = new TicTacToe();
tic.showhtml();
```

```html
<table id="tictable">
```

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to add table rows (`<tr>`). In addition note that you don't have to set the innerHTML on each iteration. Collect the tags to a screen, and in the end set the innerHTML.

```js
function TicTacToe() {
  this.board = [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]
  ];
  this.showhtml = toHTML;
}

function toHTML() {
  var gametable = document.getElementById("tictable");
  var htmlStr = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < this.board.length; i++) {
    
    htmlStr += '<tr>'; // row start
    
    for (var j = 0; j < this.board[i].length; j++) {
      htmlStr += ("<td>" + this.board[i][j] + "</td>");
    }
    
    htmlStr += '</tr>'; // row end
  }

  gametable.innerHTML = htmlStr;
}

tic = new TicTacToe();
tic.showhtml();
```

```html
<table id="tictable">
```

Comment: One important thing to point out is that you're also creating a string and editing the innerHTML all at once, instead of individually doing innerHTML on every loop iteration.

Comment: Indeed. I should mention that.

Comment: So when I created it all at once it made it all one thing instead of an individual cell?

Comment: Nope. That was because you forgot to add rows. When you used `gametable.innerHHTML` in the loop, you made the browser render each cell, which will hurt performance badly if you have a large number of items.